# How can I add data to my django db. Using excel as an input?

Tags: django

How can I add data to my django db. Using excel as an input?

I extracted the data but i don’t know to go store it in the database

I have two models patient and doctor. I have extracted the data using `xlrd`, and got a dictionary:

```
d ={“name”:list of names,”number”: list of numbers , so on }
```

I used a `forms.form` model.

Answer (score 0):

you can access excel data with pandas library, you should first make dataframe and then you can save your data using model.objects.get_or_create method in view.
before that you should first define your table in model for save data .